# Creating Crystal Report From C# & ADO.NET

Tags: c#

i need to create a crystal report from my project of employees database, means whenever i press click on a report button a report of that selected employee will be generated and shown to user, how to do this? here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome To Employee Database!", "Welcome", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string flag;
    SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRISLOGI-57EEC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            a.Open();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl1 (ID, FirstName, LastName) values (@id, @fn, @ln)", a);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", textBox2.Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", textBox3.Text);
            //da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl1", a);
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ds.Clear();
            da.Fill(ds, "tbl1");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl1"];





            flag = "1";
            if (flag == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data inserted");
                Reset();
            }
            a.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data cannot insert" + ex);
        }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        a.Open();

        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl1 SET FirstName = @fn, LastName = @ln WHERE ID = @id", a);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", textBox2.Text);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", textBox3.Text);
        //da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl1", a);
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ds.Clear();
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl1");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl1"];





            a.Close();
            flag = "1";
            if (flag == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data updated");
                Reset();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data cannot update" + ex);
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        a.Open();




        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE ID = @id", a);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);




        if ((MessageBox.Show("are you sure u want to delete", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes))
        {
            //da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl1", a);
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ds.Clear();
            da.Fill(ds, "tbl1");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl1"];

            flag = "1";
            if (flag == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data deleted");
                Reset();
            }

        }
        a.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data cannot delete" + ex);
        }

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a.Open();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl1", a);
        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        a.Close();
        ds.Clear();
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl1");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl1"];

        bs.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl1"];
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "ID"));
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "FirstName"));
        textBox3.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "LastName"));

    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        textBox1.Text =
            textBox2.Text =
            textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.MoveNext();
        selectRow();

    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.MovePrevious();
        selectRow();
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.MoveFirst();
        selectRow();
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.MoveLast();
        selectRow();
    }

    public void selectRow()
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        dataGridView1.Rows[bs.Position].Selected = true;
    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Basically you'll need to create a new Crystal Report and add it to your project.  In the report you can set up its datasource, and have it filter the data by a parameter field, which you'll supply in your code-behind.  (i.e. the selected employee)

Comment: how to do this? can u provide a sample code?

Comment: This is a good place to start:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251686.aspx

Comment: Read this links 1. http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-tutorial.htm 2. http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm 3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dq6wHrbNQTQ 4. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/1/61/crystal-reports-C-Sharp.aspx